# Unable to connect to instance

Tags: sql-server, msde

I've installed Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Desktop Engine (MSDE 2000) Release A using the following switches/parameters in the setup.ini file:

```
[Options]
SAPWD="sa"
DISABLENETWORKPROTOCOLS=0
DATADIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\SQL Server 2000\"
TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\SQL Server 2000\"
```

When I try to connect to the instance in Management Studio 17, I get the attached error.

I've been bouncing around Google and couldn't find a solution here, I cannot see why it's not working. I have an instance, it's started, so I should be able to connect to it!!

Note that I also have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed and can connect to that instance no problem.

I'm looking to replicate an issue I'm having at work but can't even get SQL Server 2000 to work!

Please do you know what might be the issue?

[image: Unable to connect to SQL Server 2000 MSDE]

Answer (score 0):

`MSSQLSERVER` is the instance id for the **default, unnamed instance**. To connect to it, you should use:

- `.`
- `(local)`
- or your machine name, or IP address

but *without* any instance name - most definitely not with `MSSQLSERVER`

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately these are not working. Before these attempts, I originally set this up with a named instance - SQL2000. In Services it was listed as MSSQL$SQL2000. It wouldn't connect with that or just with SQL2000.

Comment: @Zuno: have you tried `.\SQL2000` or `(local)\SQL2000` ??

Comment: I uninstalled-reinstalled MSDE, set the instance name as SQL2000 and tried your suggestions. Error 26 - server not found or not accessible. When installing MSDE, Windows alerts me about possible incompatibility, I guess this issue must be down to that. It's not important now to get this working, let's leave it. Thank you for your help though :)